# How to match CSV value in column get images

Tags: php, mysql

My images column data is:

```
images
------
acdfdf.jpg, bachdh.jpg, asa.jpg
```

How can I get a sorted list of all images?

```
<img src="acdfdf.jpg">
<img src="bachdh.jpg">
<img src="asa.jpg">
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming everything is in an array:

```
<?php 
   sort($images);
?>
<?php foreach($images as $image): ?>
<img src="<?php echo $image; ?>" />
<?php endforeach; ?>
```